# Is it possible editing data inside QGIS Server?

Tags: editing, qgis-server

I need to modify some field, for example i have a polygon but i would like to add a picture or pdf to it, so if someone click on the polygon he could see the picture or a document.

Is it possible modify the data on QGIS Server?

Comment: You can certainly do that offline by adding an **Action** which can load the picture or document in the required program (eg. _Image Viewer_, _Adobe Reader_). I'm no expert in QGIS Server but if you can't modify data when it's on the server then perhaps you can do it offline first and then upload it?